# VS2013 Class Diagram generator

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2013. I drag a class from Architecture Explorer to UML editor, but it failed with the following error:

```
<Error Timestamp="2015-05-27T12:24:35" Importance="High" Text="Length cannot be less than zero.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: length Reverse engineer process was stopped." />
```

This is the most detailed information I have from generator, so I stuck. I then did a googling & found an answer likes: a negative number has been pre-initialized somewhere in the code. But for god sake, there is no pre-initilized negative number anywhere in my code. Did I miss something? Please help.

Comment: I don't care about the point, but has anyone willing to tell about the -1? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to these [answers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/edd529fa-2023-4c15-a321-c3c27d1745c8/reverse-engineering-error-length-cannot-be-less-than-zero?forum=vsarch) this problem can be fixed by changing path to your solution.

Does your path contain non-english (Unicode) characters?

Comment: My solution path doesn't contain non-english characters. The namespace has one, but even if I change it to english characters, the same error still there.